# How to get exact F# version number (e.g.: 4.7.2, not just 4.7)

Tags: .net-core, f#, nuget, f#-interactive

We have a set of .NET Core projects, part of which are in F#. We want to switch to restoring NuGet packages based on a lockfile, using the `dotnet restore --locked-mode` option.

However, when I generated the lockfiles for the first time, my colleagues were unable to restore them. They got a message like this:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.301\NuGet.targets(128,5): error NU1004: The packages lock file is inconsistent with the project dependencies so restore can't be run in locked mode. Disable the RestoreLockedMode MSBuild property or pass an explicit --force-evaluate option to run restore to update the lock file. [c:\Projects\Project.sln]
```

When the colleague regenerated the lockfiles (using `dotnet restore --locked-mode --force-evaluate`), the only change we found was in the `FSharp.Core` package, which was downgraded from `4.7.2` to `4.7.1`. However, when running `dotnet fsi` command, we both see just `... F# 4.7` (and not `4.7.1` or `4.7.2`).

We are afraid that this lockfile conflict might cause issues in our CI/CD pipeline, where different versions of F# might be installed. Is it somehow possible to get the exact version number of F#? Or, at least, to infer it from the F# Interactive version number? E.g.:

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 10.10.0.0 for F# 4.7
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
```

vs

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 10.9.1.0 for F# 4.7
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
```

Or, is there another option how to force the installation of a particular F# version based on the provided lockfile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing two versions here:

- Version of the F# language
- Version of the FSharp.Core library

The major/minor versions should line up, but there are patches to the core library so you always want the latest patch version.

Specifying your FSharp.Core dependency explicitly is easiest done like so:

```
<PackageReference Update="FSharp.Core" Version="4.7.2" />
```

Although it's worth asking if you actually need to do this in the first place. For applications (not nuget packages) it's recommended to always build with the latest.

The version of FSharp.Core is pinned in a given SDK, so it always restores the same version if you build from the same SDK. I suspect you and your colleagues may not all be using the same build toolchain if it restored a different package version. One way around this is to use a `global.json` file to pin the SDK version.

Answer (score 3):

One suggestion might be disable the implicit reference to `FSharp.Core` and explicitly add it to each project. To do this, you add this property to your project:

```xml
<DisableImplicitFSharpCoreReference>true</DisableImplicitFSharpCoreReference>
```

I can't find any specific documentation for this, but you can see [in the source](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/ad451b6829282fe0af0c37b1a160ac7f322eee4d/src/fsharp/FSharp.Build/Microsoft.FSharp.NetSdk.props#L83-L101) how this reference gets added with the version dependent on the SDK and that setting this property will prevent this.

Once disabled you can then add the reference like any other package:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="FSharp.Core" Version="4.7.2" />
```

This would mean the version restored no longer depends on the SDK used to restore it.